# How can I fix the pen color on the turtle not showing up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code and I am now trying to draw my first initial. My turtle seems to have no color despite naming it to be navy blue. How do I fix this? I need the pen color to be redefined as navy blue when drawing the first initial, but when this code is ran, it draws like it is invisible?

Why is it doing this?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: In `draw_first_initial()` you lift the pen `up()` and never put if `down()` again which you probably want to do after the `goto()`

Comment: You might also want to `time.sleep(5)` after calling `draw_picture()` to give yourself a moment to enjoy your result.

Answer (score 0):

The only real issue here is the typo in the function definition. It should be `def draw_first_initial`.

The `if __name__ == "__main__"` block would be a nice to have.

### Original answer:

You're calling `main()` before the function is defined.

Instead, delete your main method and try adding this block at the bottom:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
   print("Project 1 by Amanda Basant")
   draw_picture(amanda)
```

Comment: Oops. You also have a typo in the function name!

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed the error with the typo and it worked just fine. Please check the edit on the post and I am now struggling with the pen color

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
from turtle import *
color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

[Resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)

Comment: >>> turtle.color("red", "green")
 >>> turtle.color()
 ('red', 'green')
 >>> color("#285078", "#a0c8f0")
 >>> color()
 ((40.0, 80.0, 120.0), (160.0, 200.0, 240.0))

Comment: this didn't work, can you try doing it in the form in the code please?

Answer (score 0):

In `draw_first_initial()` you lift the pen `up()` and never put if `down()` again which you probably want to do after the `goto()`. Without the pen being down no lines are drawn.

```
def draw_first_initial(turtle):
    turtle.color("navy")
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(-200,200)

    turtle.down()      # Put the pen back down now to draw your initial
    turtle.left(15)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.left(150)
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.forward(15)
    turtle.right(75)
    turtle.forward(9)
```

Comment: Yes this was my mistake! Thank you :)